# Formula editor for better overview over nested functions

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to change the single-row formula bar of spreadsheets (e.g. Google Sheets) to some sort of editor with indenting to make formulas more clearly structured?

I kind of struggle having a lot of nested functions in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

The main way to use multiple rows for your operators is to use Alt+Enter when in the formula bar.

I'm not sure about indenting, but you can use the general format of "four spaces" to notify a `tab` being used

[image: Showing lines and indents]